# Filtering out null values from a table in django

Tags: python, django

so I'm trying to create a view of a table on a different page which removes all the records where dep_time=' '

views.py:

```
from postlog.models import Flight, DepartureTime

def HomePageView(request):
    val = DepartureTime.objects.exclude(dep_time__exact='')
    val = val.values('fl_no')
    links = [None]*val.count()
    for i in range(val.count()): 
        links = Flight.objects.filter(fl_no=int(val[i].get('fl_no')))
    args = { 'links' : links }
    return render(request, 'base_home.html', args)
```

HTML file:

```
{%extends 'base_template1.html' %}
{% load static from staticfiles %}
{% load crispy_forms_tags %}


<!DOCTYPE html>
  {% block title %} Home {% endblock %}

 {% block content %}   
  <table class="table table-bordered" id="departures">
    <thead> 
      <tr>
        <th class="text-center" scope="col">Flight Number</th>
          <th class="text-center" scope="col">Departure Time</th>
          <th class="text-center" scope="col">Destination</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      {% for link in links %}
      <tr>
        <td class="text-center">{{link.fl_no}}</td>
          <td class="text-center">{{link.dep_time}}</td>
          <td class="text-center">{{link.dest}}</td>
      </tr>
      {%endfor%}
    </tbody>
  </table>
  {% endblock %}
```

my models.py file:

```
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.
class FlightNum(models.Model):
    fl_no =models.CharField(max_length=5,primary_key=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.fl_no

class Destination(models.Model):
    fl_no= models.OneToOneField(FlightNum,on_delete=models.CASCADE,related_name='fl1')
    dest= models.CharField(max_length=15,blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.dest

class Parking(models.Model):
    fl_no= models.OneToOneField(FlightNum,on_delete=models.CASCADE,related_name='fl2')
    park_bay= models.CharField(max_length=3)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.park_bay

class DepartureTime(models.Model):
    fl_no= models.OneToOneField(FlightNum,on_delete=models.CASCADE,related_name='fl3')
    dep_time= models.CharField(max_length=9, default= 'NA')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.dep_time

class Airline(models.Model):
    airline = models.CharField(max_length=15)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.airline

class Flight(models.Model):
    fl_no= models.OneToOneField(FlightNum,on_delete=models.CASCADE, primary_key=True, related_name='fl4')
    park_bay= models.ForeignKey(Parking, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    dest= models.ForeignKey(Destination, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    dep_time= models.ForeignKey(DepartureTime, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    inbound= models.CharField(max_length=15,blank=True)
    airline= models.ForeignKey(Airline,max_length=15, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    arr_time= models.TimeField(blank=True, null=True)
```

forms.py:

```
class flightnoForm(ModelForm):
            class Meta:
                model = FlightNum
                fields = '__all__'
                labels = {
                    'fl_no' : ('Flight Number')
                }

class destForm(ModelForm):
            class Meta:
                model = Destination
                fields = ('dest',)
                labels = {
                    'dest' : ('Destination')
                }

            def save(self, a, commit=True):
                instance = super(destForm, self).save(commit=False)

                if not self.instance.pk:
                    # create
                    if commit:
                        instance.fl_no = a
                        instance.save()
                return instance

class parkForm(ModelForm):
            class Meta:
                model = Parking
                fields = ('park_bay',)
                labels = {
                    'park_bay' : ('Parking Bay')
                }
            def save(self, a, commit=True):
                instance = super(parkForm, self).save(commit=False)

                if not self.instance.pk:
                    # create
                    if commit:
                        instance.fl_no = a
                        instance.save()
                return instance 

class deptForm(ModelForm):
            class Meta:
                model = DepartureTime
                fields = ('dep_time',)
                labels = {
                    'dep_time' : ('Departure Time')
                }

            def save(self, a, commit=True):
                instance = super(deptForm, self).save(commit=False)

                if not self.instance.pk:
                    # create
                    if commit:
                        instance.fl_no = a
                        instance.save()
                return instance   

class flightForm(ModelForm):
            class Meta:
                model = Flight
                fields =('inbound','airline','arr_time')
                labels = {
                    'airline' :('Airline'),
                    'inbound' : ('Inbound'),
                    'arr_time' : ('Arrival Time'),
                }
            def save(self, a, b, c, d, commit=True):
                instance = super(flightForm, self).save(commit=False)

                if not self.instance.pk:
                    # create
                    if commit:
                        instance.fl_no = a
                        instance.park_bay = b
                        instance.dest = c
                        instance.dep_time = d
                        instance.save()
                return instance
```

and the views.py for the above forms:

```
def FlightAddPageView(request):
        if request.method =="POST":
            formA = flightnoForm(request.POST, prefix= 'flno')
            formB = parkForm(request.POST, prefix= 'park')
            formC = destForm(request.POST, prefix= 'dest')
            formD = deptForm(request.POST, prefix= 'dept')
            formE = flightForm(request.POST, prefix= 'figh')
            if formA.is_valid() and formB.is_valid() and formC.is_valid() and formD.is_valid() and formE.is_valid():
                a = formA.save()
                b = formB.save(a)
                c = formC.save(a)
                d = formD.save(a)
                e = formE.save(a, b, c, d)
            return redirect(reverse('flight_list'))
        else:
            formA = flightnoForm(request.POST, prefix= 'flno')
            formB = parkForm(request.POST, prefix= 'park')
            formC = destForm(request.POST, prefix= 'dest')
            formD = deptForm(request.POST, prefix= 'dept')
            formE = flightForm(request.POST, prefix= 'figh')
            args = {'formA' : formA, 'formB': formB, 'formC' : formC, 'formD' : formD, 'formE' : formE}
            return render(request, 'flight_add.html', args)
```

using the function `HomePageView` prints only one record I know its because of the for loop but I'm not sure how to fix it would really appreciate if someone could help

Comment: Can you please share your models. At first sight it looks like you are missing a `ForeignKey`.

Comment: I'd be happy to recommend a cleaner way to do this, there are a few aspects of your request handler that are a bit off. Can you add to your question the portions of your model definition showing the relationship between Flight and Departure models?  You can also remove the template code, that is not useful here

Comment: thank you so much. have edited the post

Comment: I guess Willem will answer this question. I would comment on your model structure, which is very 'unusual'.  You want to build on a good foundation - your data model is your foundation. Perhaps this is not the place to discuss this, so just 1 comment - I see nothing to be gained by breaking data between so many models. For example, if a Flight has a flight number, just make flight number an attribute of Flight. Don't put that one field in a different model. I recommend you invest a little time reading about data model design and then come back and redesign.

Comment: I'm so sorry. I was just experimenting with django

Comment: No need to apologize! Glad you are experimenting. Learn Django by messing around with it.  But, if you are going to write a real application, I recommend you also seek out some instruction on fundamentals of data modeling.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply filter with:

```
def HomePageView(request):
    links = Flight.objects.exclude(
        fl_no__fl3__dep_time__exact=''
    )
    return render(request, 'base_home.html', { 'links' : links })
```

It might however be better to make `dep_time` a (NULLable) [**`TimeField`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#timefield), since then the only possible values are times, and `NULL`, hence you do more validation.

Furthermore, like [@Sayse says](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58805027/filtering-out-null-values-from-a-table-in-django/58805190#comment103890181_58805190), your `Flight` itself has a `dep_time` as well. This looks like (severe) data-duplication. I would strongly advise that you take a look at your modeling, and try to eliminate as much data duplication as (reasonably) possible. After all, keeping data in sync, even on the same database, tends to be a hard problem.

Comment: You can filter it loads more, the `Flight` model has a `dep_time` so just check that

Comment: i have rendered three different forms in the same page which might be causing some problems

Comment: @Sayse: yes, but that is not per se equivalent. Here we join over the `fl_no`. But it is likely indeed data duplication, which is a severe anti-pattern.

Comment: Okay thank you so much I will try to normalize my tables

Answer (score 0):

I see that you have set a default value for `dep_time`, which is `'NA'`, so I guess you also want to exclude those values. To keep things simpler, you can do this:

```py
def HomePageView(request):
    links = Flight.objects.exclude(fl_no__fl3__dep_time__in=['','NA'])  # this filters dep_time with empty ('') or 'NA' values
    args = { 'links' : links }
    return render(request, 'base_home.html', args)
```